# Job running ssis package gets error : 'The system cannot find the path specified'

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I have an ssis package that uses excel files. I am using the `Run As` with an admin account.

when I call it from a batch file it runs fine

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /SQL "\SOME_SSIS_PACKAGE" /SERVER "MYSERVER,PORT" /DECRYPT "Password" /VALIDATE  /REPORTING E
```

when I schedule it as a job, it fails with the error message  : `'The system cannot find the path specified'`

what path are you trying to find ?

the excel file path is accessed like this : `\\server\folder\template.xls`
when I'm logged on the server and punch in the address `\\server\folder\template.xls` the file is found

Comment: This sounds like a setup problem in that the service running the job doesn't have the path correct. This should be on superuser.

Comment: it's the only job with this problem, other jobs run fine

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that Sql Server agent jobs run in the context of the user running the SQL Server Agent service (which is not the same service as SQL server).

You can also define your job to be executed in the context of a [proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189064.aspx) account

Comment: It's already running with a proxy account.
I am using the Run As with an admin account.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is because the server calling the job doesn't have rights to the template.xls. The file resides on \ServerA but the ServerB calling the job may not be able to see it so check those rights.

Comment: I'm running the batch file from the sql server running the job, why doesn't the batch file fail?

The sql server running the job uses the 'Run As' with a domain admin account

Comment: Hmm odd. Have you tried removing that particular job from SQLAgent and readding it?

Comment: Yes I did remove the job and recreate it, still failling